# How to hide the navigation menu in a single wordpress page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a site powered by wordpress.  I need to hide the navigation menu in two specific pages but I couldn´t  do it.

This is the page:

[image]

The menu is appearing like this:

[image]

In the bottom left side of the page. It´s need to be hide or remove.

Above, is the  html of the menu

[image]

I tried  this use this code:

```
.mob-menu-header-holder .mobmenu .mobmenur-container .mob-menu-left-panel .mobmenu_content .leftmtop  .mob-menu-right-panel{display: none;}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this in the admin?  Your CSS selector is pretty specific and likely to miss the target.  Use dev tools to get a selector that works.

Comment: What is your website URL? Are you on WordPress.com or a self hosted WordPress install?

Comment: Is a self hosted wordpress install.  This is the url: http://rentadvisor.cl/

Answer (score 0):

please try add this code in your functions.php

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_css_head');
function add_css_head() {
if ( is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) || is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) ) {
?>
  <style>
      .your-css-class {
         display:none

       }
  </style>
 <?php
 } 
}
```

if one of page you want to hide is frontpage you can use this

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_css_head');
function add_css_head() {
if ( is_front_page() || is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) ) {
?>
  <style>
      .your-css-class {
         display:none

       }
  </style>
 <?php
 } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have to access your wordpress files. Then find custom .css or .less file if it's exist. And then add this code line in this file. But this line affect to whole site pages. So, if you want to affect only two pages, you have to add some codes to in your theme's index.php (I guess) file.

> .mobmenu{ display:none!important; }

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your answer. 1) You asked if you've access to WP files but that doesn't mean anything, you should've asked if you use WP.com or the open source. 2) Your way of inserting CSS to a WP theme is totally incorrect, it'll still work somehow but is a hack. 3) You didn't answer the actual question.

Comment: Thanks @junaid you are right. But I only wanted to help. And I wanted to ask some questions (like yours) to Rivero but I don't have enough reputation-points to add a comment under the question. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Also Rivero, I tried my suggestion on your site (rentadvisor.cl), it's working.